# Can Visual Studio 2010 outlining be fixed for VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2010 we have noticed a few annoyances (including issues with resource based imagelists on 64bit systems), but none have been as bad as the way VS 2010 shows outlined methods for VB.NET.

Previously in VS 2008 when a method is outlined you got the method outline with correctly colored keywords. Now all you get is an outline in grey. This outline looks identical to a collapsed XML comment.

To add to the confusion if your method has an XML comment and the method signature is word wrapped you get two outlines seperated by an empty line in the same color when both are collapsed.

This doesn't affect C# only VB.NET. Am I doing something wrong or is this a defect in VS 2010?

Comment: Did you try modifiying the colors?

Comment: @leppie - Yes I have to no effect. But as the colors are shared between C# and VB.NET and this is only afecting VB.NET I think it goes deeper than colors.

Comment: I repro, this looks very much by design and a side-effect of the editor rewrite.  Connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can safely say this is not going to be fixed!